# iPhone 3D Engine for a WebGL Bike Configurator

Tags: iphone, frameworks, webgl, 3d-engine

I have developed a WebGL bike configurator demo using Three.js. Given the fact that WebGL is not yet supported on iOS Safari, I have to port my app to Objective-C. Which 3D engine do you recommend?

What do you think about NinevehGL and iSGL3D framework? 
http://nineveh.gl/
http://isgl3d.com/

EDIT: I need free/opensource frameworks

EDIT 2: I have found a great comparison of open source frameworks althought NinevehGL framework is not mentioned:

http://maniacdev.com/2009/08/the-open-source-iphone-game-engine-comparison/

Comment: Would you mind sharing your code for the configurator using Three.js? I am also looking to build something like this, but for shoes. Thanks!

Comment: I can't share the code. I just can tell you that you have to think about how to handle displacements between dependant parts. By the way, do you know about any free/opensource 3d engine for iPhone that could be useful to me?

Comment: OK that's cool, I understand. Did you figure out how to do this by reading up on Three.js or did you find any helpful tutorials or articles? :) I'm sorry I don't know any 3d engine frameworks, I'm limited to HTML/CSS/JS myself (which is why I'm looking for a non-flash solution for a configurator ;)).

Comment: I just learned Three.js by reading the source code of some of their examples and the source code of their example gui (all of these is available on their Github). Previously I read this http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?page_id=1217 but you won't need it because Three.js let you forget about WebGL calls. However, it could be interisting for you to read lessons 1 to 6. Finally, take a look at http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/ so your JS code mantains as clean as possible. **By the way, next time try to open a new question for your doubts. Thanks!!!**

Comment: There is an up-to-date list of Open Source iPhone Game Engines that might be useful http://mobilegameengines.com/iphone/open_source_game_engines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you are comfortable with javascript I would suggest using [Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/) so you can code in UnityScript which is also ECMAScript derived.

Comment: Thanks, tomorrow I will take a look at it. Apart from JavaScript, I'm also familiar with Objective-C, Flex and PHP

Comment: I realized that this framework is not free So I edited the question to include that I need fre/opensource frameworks

Comment: Sorry, you were right. Unity has a free version. After my deep search it is the engine I will use cause I think it has a great potential. Moreover, Nineveh GL is yet in beta stage and iSGL3D hasn't been updated for a long while. It seems main developer of it can't continue with framework maintenance: http://groups.google.com/group/isgl3d/browse_thread/thread/fc5e90e2ccbfc7f8?pli=1

Comment: Ops, for Unity iOS development you have to pay some money although it's affordable.

Answer (score 1):

After trying myself NinevehGL and ISGL3D by doing a small demo for my needs I can say the following:

-**NinevehGL 0.9.2:** It's an easy to use framework. It's great but it lacks of many features yet. However, when more features gets added, it will be a great framework. I'm sure! The API is fully documented and you can install documentation directly on XCode.

-**ISGL3D 1.2.3:** It's more difficult to use. It has a lot of features. However, it has bugs which are not being solved. The reason for that is main developer don't have time to mantain code. Other developers has shown interest in continuing his work and have moved code to Github. But activity there is very low. What is active is isgl3d google group. The API is very well documented on framework's web.

So now I will try Unity like @ade suggested me...

EDIT:

-**Unity:** It's really a great framework. I have already done a demo and I like it over the rest. It is my choice now because 3D file importing system is very great and you can export your work to multiple platforms. If you like JavaScript you will like it. What is important is that if you have doubts or errors in your code, there is a lot of material online to help you in Unity answers ( http://answers.unity3d.com/ ). Finally, to get started check out this URL: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/12321/how-can-i-start-learning-unity-fast-list-of-tutori.html